# Windows Batch File, Route Output of EXE called in Batch File

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

In my batch file, I call a EXE and would like the output to be redirected to a file. In the PowerShell command line, it would look something like this:

```
prog.exe file.txt | Out-File results\results.txt -Encoding ascii
```

The above works in the command line. In my batch file, I have written it as this:

```
prog.exe file.txt | powershell -Command "Out-File results\file.txt -Encoding ascii"
```

When I run the batch file, the results file gets created but contains zero content. How can write this to behave like I need it too?

Comment: What about `PowerShell -Command "prog.exe file.txt | Out-File results\results.txt -Encoding ascii"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work in a batch file:

```
prog.exe file.txt > results\results.txt
```

If you want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` use:

```
prog.exe file.txt > results\results.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: What about the encoding?

Comment: Check out `chcp` and/or `cmd /u` and `cmd /a`.

Comment: ASCII is default for cmd.exe. You can use /A for ASCII and /U for Unicode when calling cmd.exe or use `chcp 65001` to set it to Unicode at the top of your batch file.

Comment: @StephenP: cmd.exe's default code page is the active OEM code page, which in the case of single-byte code pages is a _superset_ of ASCII. `/A` selects the _ANSI_ code page, not ASCII, and only for cmd.exe's _internal commands_; similarly, `/U` for "Unicode" (read: UTF-16LE) only applies to internal commands as well. `chcp 65001` selects the UTF-8 code page; UTF-8 is a variable-width Unicode encoding that is a superset of ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

[kichik's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583063/45375) shows you an effective solution using batch-file features alone.

Unless you have a need to create files with an encoding *other than* ASCII or the active OEM code page, there's no need to get PowerShell involved - it'll only slow things down.

That said, you can choose a different code page via `chcp` in `cmd.exe`, but for output to a file only `65001` for UTF-8 really makes sense, but note that the resulting file will have *no* BOM - unlike when you use `Out-File -Encoding utf8` in Windows PowerShell.

If you do need to use PowerShell - e.g., to create UTF-16LE ("Unicode") files or UTF-8 files *with BOM* -  you'll have to use `$Input` with a PowerShell-internal pipe in your PowerShell command in order to access the stdin stream (i.e., what was piped in):

```
prog.exe file.txt | powershell -c "$Input | Out-File results\file.txt -Encoding ascii"
```

Note that only characters representable in the active code page (as reflected in `chcp`) will be recognized by PowerShell and can be translated into potentially different encodings.

Choosing `-Encoding ascii` would actually transliterate characters outside the (7-bit) ASCII range to *literal* `?` characters, which would result in *loss of information*.